# Text at beginning of List of Symbols

Tags: glossaries

I want to add a text at the beginning of the List of Symbols (which I create with the `glossaries` package), i.e., directly after the heading and before the first symbol. Is this possible?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[toc, nonumberlist, style=altlist]{glossaries}
\newglossary[slg]{symbolslist}{syi}{syg}{List of Symbols}
\makenoidxglossaries
\newglossaryentry{determinant}{
name=\ensuremath{\det(A)},
sort={det},
description={The determinant of the matrix $A$},
type=symbolslist
}
\begin{document}
text
\glsaddall
\printnoidxglossary[type=symbolslist]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [`glossaries`](http://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries) [user manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.pdf) (section **10 Displaying a glossary**):

> Information can be added to the start of the glossary (after the title and
>   before the main body of the glossary) by redefining `\glossarypreamble`. For example:
>
> ```
> \renewcommand{\glossarypreamble}{Numbers in italic indicate primary definitions.}
> ```
>
> This needs to be done before the glossary is displayed.
>
> If you want a different preamble per glossary you can use `\setglossarypreamble[<type>]{<preamble text>}`. If `<type>` is omitted, `\glsdefaulttype` is used. For example:
>
> ```
> \setglossarypreamble{Numbers in italic indicate primary definitions.}
> ```
>
> This will print the given preamble text for the main glossary, but not have
>   any preamble text for any other glossaries.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[toc, nonumberlist, style=altlist]{glossaries}

\newglossary[slg]{symbolslist}{syi}{syg}{List of Symbols}

\makenoidxglossaries

\newglossaryentry{determinant}{
  name=\ensuremath{\det(A)},
  sort={det},
  description={The determinant of the matrix $A$},
  type=symbolslist
}
\setglossarypreamble[symbolslist]{This is a preamble.}

\begin{document}

text

\glsaddall

\printnoidxglossary[type=symbolslist]

\end{document}
```